How to disable pg_stat_statements on amazon RDS
In order to enable tracking with pg_stat_statements on amazon RDS posgress, you need to run this statement in DBeaver or similar:
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_stat_statements;
Then you can immediately do things like
select * from pg_stat_statements
However, if you wish to turn it off for a period (Without rebooting the DB) to not impact perormance, how do you do it?
I don't have access to the CLI, only sql.
I see one can do this:
DROP EXTENSION IF exists pg_stat_statements
But I'm not sure what the effect if this is exactly, as if I recreate the extension, and query the pg_stat_statements table, it seems to have carried on in there are a lot of rows already in it.
